# Group mysql query results in php generated table and add results of table row together with same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large MySQL table which looks like this:

```
job_number        time_on        time_off
111               18:50:10       18:51:18
222               18:13:09       19:33:42
111               07:12:04       08:30:20
333               10:34:03       12:53:10
444               14:54:25       12:11:04
444               10:31:48       16:34:53
111               17:21:41       20:21:41
(type: Varchar)   (type: time)   (type: time)
```

I want to find the difference between the time_on and time_off fields for each job_number and echo them in the $total_time column.
If there are multiple rows with the same job_number (111, 444), i want to be able to find the difference between the time_on and the time_off for that row but also add these values together.
I would like to make sure there is only one row of each unique job number with the combined times like so:

```
Job    Total Time // ($total_time = $time_off - $time_on)
111    04:19:34 // ((18:51:18 - 18:50:10) + (08:30:20 - 07:12:04) +  (20:21:41 - 17:21:41))
222    01:20:33 // (19:33:42 - 18:13:09)
333    02:19:07 // (12:53:10 - 10:34:03)
444    08:46:26 // ((16:34:53 - 10:31:48) + (14:54:25 - 12:11:04))
```

the results will be formatted in a simple table like so:

```
<table>  
    <tr>  
        <th>Job</th>  
        <th>Total Time</th>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td>111</th>  
        <td>04:19:34</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
        <td>222</th>  
        <td>01:20:33</th>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

How would i go about doing this?
I would prefer to use PHP to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Could you specify in the OP what job ID's the different times have? It'd give a lot of info to the person helping you.

Comment: Note that the times used to construct your example output are not the same as those given in the example data (which is why the result of my query below differs from that above).

Comment: I have tried a while loop but do not understand it enough to have any success.
In the while loop i used this:
// looping through each row with a while loop
    $table[$row['job_number']][] = $row['time_on'];
    $table[$row['job_number']][] = $row['time_off'];
and was able to create an array with all the nessassary fields but didn't know what to do from there.

I would prefer to use PHP to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in SQL:

```sql
SELECT   job_number,
         SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_off) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_on)))
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY job_number
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acbdd/1/0).

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I will use this if i am not able to work out how to achieve this using PHP. I say this because i am already SELECTing these fields, along with others, from the database for use somewhere else on the page and so it does not seem right to select them twice. Also, thanks for pointing out that my two examples are different, i will fix them up now